# SQL update attribute

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a table of milestones in which the primary key is Id_milestone and a table with tasks where foreign key is id_milestone. For each task I attribute completion in percentage. The milestone also have attribute of completion in percentage. I need to update the completion of the milestone at 100 percent until they have completed **all the tasks** set to 100 percent. I have a DropDownList with interval 10 percent and users update the progress. Sorry for my English.

```
CREATE TABLE Milestone 
     ( 
      ID_milestone INTEGER  NOT NULL ,      
      Nazev_milniku VARCHAR2 (30) ,      
     )  ;   

CREATE TABLE Milestone_complete 
     ( 
      ID_milestone INTEGER  NOT NULL , 
      Completed INTEGER   
     )  ;

CREATE TABLE Tasks 
     ( 
      ID_tasks INTEGER  NOT NULL , 
      ID_milestone INTEGER  NOT NULL , 
      Name_task VARCHAR2 (30) ,  
     )  ;

 CREATE TABLE Tasks_complete 
     ( 
      ID_task INTEGER  NOT NULL , 
      Completed INTEGER         
     )  ;
```

Comment: how do you know that the task is completed? do you have more columns? please add it on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will calculate the percentage of your milestones using all percentages of your tasks.

```
UPDATE [milestones]
SET [percentage] = (SELECT AVG(pecentage) FROM [tasks] WHERE [tasks].[id_milestone] = [milestones].[id])
```

If you want to set e.g. a status flag like [completed] you can do something like this:

```
UPDATE [milestones]
SET [completed] = (CASE WHEN (SELECT AVG(pecentage) FROM [tasks] WHERE [tasks].[id_milestone] = [milestones].[id]) = 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

This is just a guess what you want as you didn't comppletely show us your tables, structure, etc.
Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Your table `Milestone` need a column `percentage` or do you want to write the result in the other table Milestone_complete? I don't understand why you have those additional tables.
So we guess you have a column `percentage` in your `Milestone` table. In this case the SQL is like this:

```
UPDATE [Milestone]
SET [percentage] = (SELECT AVG(pecentage) 
                    FROM [Tasks] 
                    WHERE [Tasks].[ID_milestone] = [Milestone].[ID_milestone])
```

If you want to write the result in the `Completed' column in the`Milestone_complete` table, then do it like this:

```
UPDATE [Milestone_complete]
SET [percentage] = (SELECT AVG(pecentage) 
                    FROM [Tasks] 
                    WHERE [Tasks].[ID_milestone] = [Milestone].[ID_milestone])
FROM [Milestone_complete]
JOIN [Milestone] ON [Milestone].[ID_milestone] = [Milestone_Complete].[ID_milestone]
```

Or do you only want to insert result into `Milestone_Complete` if all tasks of the milestone is 100%?
I do not know if you already have a record in the compelted table or need to add on in case.
I assume you have one and want to set completed to e.g. 1 (0 = not completed).

```
UPDATE [Milestone_complete]
SET [completed] = 1
FROM [Milestone_complete]
JOIN [Milestone] ON [Milestone].[ID_milestone] = [Milestone_Complete].[ID_milestone]
WHERE (SELECT AVG(percentage) 
       FROM [Tasks] 
       WHERE [Tasks].[ID_milestone] = [Milestone].[ID_milestone])=100
```

I didn't test anything of it, so not sure if it works, but as I do not 100% your approach you need to modify to your own needs. Hope it helps. Next time you ask a question concentrate on a clear, complete and understandable question, make it easier.

Comment: This works, but select selected average percentage from all tasks.

Comment: But this is how it should work imho. If you want a total percentage for your milestone, get the averag from all tasks. If you select only those with 100 percent, then your milestone average will be 100 as well which don't tell you any useful information.

Comment: If i have 2 milestones and this milestone1 have 2 task, which is 100% completed and milestone2 have 2 task, which is 0% completed, this select selected avg 50% and insert nothing.

Comment: @Mirek Well you have to modify your WHERE statement of your SUBSELECT to your fits. You didn't show us the table structure, so you have to modify it, so the select only give you the tasks related to your milestone. I made a sample WHERE statement, just modify it to your needs.

Comment: Can you suggest me some instructions how to modify where statement, because I have no idea. Thanks.

Comment: @Mirek added some samples in my answer.

Comment: Yes, I want to update result into Milestone_Complete if all tasks of the milestone is 100%.

Comment: UPDATE milestone_complete
SET completed = 100
FROM milestone_complete
JOIN milestone ON milestone.ID_milestone = milestone_complete.ID_milestone
JOIN tasks ON tasks.ID_milestone = milestone.ID_milestone
JOIN tasks_complete ON tasks.ID_tasks = tasks_complete.ID_tasks
where AVG(tasks_complete.completed)=100

Comment: But I have this message. An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Try replave `WHERE`with `HAVING`

Comment: I tried it, but... Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'HAVING'.

Comment: Changed the last UPDATE example. Try this, there tasks are in a subquery.

Comment: Did´t work, the same problem and when I replace where with having.Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'HAVING'.

Comment: I don't have this keyword in my last example. Check it out.

Comment: I know, in first try I have this message...An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: I tried it out now myself, my last SQL works perfectly. BUT it looks like you do ont work on ms sql server... you work with oracle? Good luck then, there I don't know the difference on the syntax. Probably nearly the same with some small differences.

Comment: Sorry, it´s work, I have mistake in table name. Thank you very much for your time.